# This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Access Check Failed!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

Full error that shows up when I visit the page in community builder that component is on: 
[image]

Didnt start heppening until Winter 17 release. The lightning component still works, also. Not sure where the issue is...

Component:

```
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="boolean"
                    default="false"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="votes" type="Public_Article_Rating__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newVote" type="Public_Article_Rating__c"
                    default="{'sobjectType':'Public_Article_Rating__c',
                             'upVote__c':'',
                             'downVote__c':'',
                             'Comments__c ':'',
                             'Article_URL__c':'', 
                             }"/>

    <div class="container">    
        <br></br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><h3><strong>Was this article helpful?</strong></h3></span>
        <br></br>
        <form aura:id="formChange">
            <table class="votingTableBlock">
                <div id="ratingArea">

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="voteBlock">
                                    <div class="upVote">
                                        <label>
                                            <ui:inputRadio aura:id="voteUp" value="{!v.newVote.upVote__c}" 
                                                           name="voters" click="{!c.addClass}" /><img src="https://7e4fd7937e7f9f526372-765592892b8ce439d4f7bb102eb57673.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/SC_assets/img/Product_Images/Thumbs-Up.png"></img>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hiddenURLField">
                                        <ui:inputText aura:id="articleURL" value="{!v.newVote.Article_URL__c}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="downVote">
                                    <label>
                                        <ui:inputRadio aura:id="voteDown" value="{!v.newVote.downVote__c}" 
                                                       name="voters" click="{!c.addClass}"/><img src="https://7e4fd7937e7f9f526372-765592892b8ce439d4f7bb102eb57673.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/SC_assets/img/Product_Images/Thumbs-Down.png"></img>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </div>

            </table>
            <div class="commentBlock">
                <div aura:id="commentsTarget" class="commentsArea"><span class="commentQuestion">Please feel free to provide any feedback or suggestions.</span>
                    <br></br>
                    <ui:inputTextArea aura:id="comments"
                                      value="{!v.newVote.Comments__c}" rows="4" cols="50"/>
                    <td>
                        <ui:button label="Submit" class="btn btn-warning"
                                   press="{!c.createVote}"/>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div aura:id="thankYou" class="thankYou">
            <span>Thank you. Your feedback has been recorded.</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
{
    createVote : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newVote = component.get("v.newVote");
        var block = component.find('formChange');
        var thanks = component.find('thankYou');

            helper.createVote(component, newVote);
            $A.util.removeClass(block, 'formChange');
            $A.util.addClass(block, 'formBlock');
            $A.util.removeClass(thanks, 'thankYou');
    },

        addClass : function(cmp, event){
            var cmpTarget = cmp.find('commentsTarget');
            var upVote = cmp.find('voteUp');
            var downVote = cmp.find('voteDown');

            $A.util.toggleClass(cmpTarget, 'commentsArea');
        },

            doInit: function(cmp) {
                cmp.find("articleURL").set("v.value", window.location.href);
            }
}
```

Helper:

```
({
    createVote : function(component, vote) {
        this.upsertVote(component, vote, function(a){
            var votes = component.get("v.votes");
            votes.push(a.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.votes", votes);

        });
},

    upsertVote : function(component, vote, callback){
        var action = component.get("c.saveVote");
        action.setParams({
            "vote": vote
        });
         action.setCallback(this, function(response)
                            {
                                var state = response.getState();
                                if (state === "SUCCESS")
                                {
                                    //Do stuff if call from server is a success
                                }
                                else if (state === "ERROR")
                                {
                                    var errors = response.getError();
                                    if (errors)
                                    {
                                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message)
                                        {
                                            console.log("Error in callback: " +
                                                       errors[0].message);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        console.log("Unhandled error");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    updateVote: function(cmp) {
    if (cmp.get("v.voteUp")) {
        var disabled = $A.util.getBooleanValue(cmp.get("v.voteUp")); 
        var checkBox = cmp.find("voteUp");
        if (checkBox) {
            var element = checkBox.getElement();
            if (element) {
                if (disabled) {
                    element.setAttribute('disabled');
                } else {
                    element.removeAttribute('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
})
```

Not sure if relevant CSS:

```
.THIS .voteBlock{
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.THIS .commentBlock{
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.THIS .commentQuestion{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.THIS .commentsArea{
    display: none;
}
.THIS input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}
.THIS label > input + img{
    margin: 10px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 65px;
        cursor: pointer;
}
.THIS .upVote label > input:checked + img{
    border:2px solid #00ac00;
}
.THIS .downVote label > input:checked + img{
    border:2px solid red;
}
.THIS .uiButton {
    width: 150px;
}
.THIS .hiddenURLField {
    display: none;
}
.THIS .formBlock {
    display: none;
}
.THIS .thankYou {
    display: none;
}
.THIS button.uiButton--default.uiButton{
    background-color: #CC7A00;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is no attribute named **voteUp** in your component.